Different behaviour of node.style.setProperty and node.setAttribute
Expected that setProperty and setAttribute should have had same effect on element.
What is the reason for this?
I cannot use setAttribute for my element , what can be alternate solution to get the expected result.


element1 = document.getElementById("test1")
element2 = document.getElementById("test2")
element1.style.setProperty("font-family", 'Lato\\2c \\20 Helvetica\\20 Neue\\2c \\20 Helvetica\\3b ')

//and 

element2.setAttribute("style", 'font-family:Lato\\2c \\20 Helvetica\\20 Neue\\2c \\20 Helvetica\\3b ')
<div id='test1'>Test1</div>
<div id='test2'>Test2</div>



gives
<div id="test1" style="font-family: "Lato,Helvetica ";">Test1</div>
<div id="test2" style="font-family:Lato\2c Helvetica\20">Test2</div>


setAttribute() does not process CSS escape sequences properly. The browser sees the exact string Lato\2c \20 Helvetica\20 Neue\2c \20 Helvetica\3b instead of translating it to Lato, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica.

I don't know why escape characters were being used, but here's a method without them.


element1 = document.getElementById("test1")
element2 = document.getElementById("test2")
element1.style.setProperty("font-family", "Lato, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica;")

//and 

element2.setAttribute("style", "font-family:Lato, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica;")
<div id='test1'>Test1</div>
<div id='test2'>Test2</div>



